# Remove column header from sql query output in powershell

Tags: powershell, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-sql

I want to remove column header from sql server query output. I did the search but not found any solution. I have a script.

```
$Database = "temp"
$Server = "localhost"

$AttachmentPath = "output.csv"


# Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter

$SqlQuery = "select cc.DepartmentID , cc.Name  from HumanResources.Department cc"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$nRecs | Out-Null

#Populate Hash Table

$objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]

#Export Hash Table to CSV File

$objTable | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

When i run this query i am getting output like this.

```
#TYPE System.Data.DataRow           
ID  Name
12  Document Control
1   Engineering
16  Executive
14  Facilities and Maintenance
10  Finance
9   Human Resources
```

I want to remove ID and Name (Column Header) from the output. No column header in output.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the type info either, you could use `ConvertTo-csv` (which outputs to the pipeline) and then skip the first 2 lines:

```
$objTable | ConvertTo-Csv | select -Skip 2 > $AttachmentPath
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue. I am getting output like this.12Document Control. In a single column.